# How do I add code to print "Success" or "Failure" based on return values from a move in navigating the maze?

Tags: java

```
public class P4 {
public static void main( String[ ] args ){
    // Create maze
            String fileName = args[0];
            Maze maze = new Maze(fileName);
            System.out.println("Maze name: " + fileName);

            // Get dimensions
            int mazeWidth = maze.getWidth();
            int mazeHeight = maze.getHeight();
            System.out.println("Maze width: " + mazeWidth);
            System.out.println("Maze height: " + mazeHeight);
```

I asked this question earlier, but I do not think I added enough detail. The exact instructions for this part of the project are:

1. Add code to print "Success" or "Failure" based on the return value from each move.
2. The maze object also has a method called maze.isDone() that returns a boolean.
3. The boolean is true when the student has found the Java icon, otherwise it is false.
4. Add enough calls to maze.moveRight() to make the student find the Java icon.
5. Add a call maze.isDone() before and after the last move, and print the result.

I entered an "if (true)" statement and then had it print out the word "Success", but I do not think that is correct because it is not printing "Failure" if a move is not legal in the maze (ie. entering a move that would move out of the boundaries of the maze). So when I enter "maze.moveRight(); to move the little person in the maze, it prints "Success", but it prints it after all of my moves, like if I input "maze.moveRight(); and then "maze.moveLeft();" it prints "success" after both moves rather than after each, how do I get it to print after each? Also, it prints the word "Success" the line after it states what row the character moved to, like

```
Moved to row 0, column 1
Moved to row 0, column 0
Success
```

how do I get it to print something like "Moved to row 0, column 0: Success"?
I appreciate all the help, you do not have to give me answers because I want to understand this, so helpful tips would be more appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you show the section where you use the if(true) statement.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, without seeing how your maze class operates, it's not really possible to tell What you're doing.

However, if you're referring to how to make it all on one line. Look into java's System.Out.print() function. If you're simply using #println() every time, it is creating a new line on each call so it wont append it to the end of your line.